# Something like "qualified this" but for accessing members of nested classes instead of the enclosing class

Tags: java, nested-class

```
public class TopLevel {

    private void someMethod() {
        Nested.this.someMethod(); // compile error
    }

    private class Nested {
        private void someMethod() {
            TopLevel.this.someMethod(); // so-called "qualified this": OK
        }
    }

}
```

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to access `Nested`'s `someMethod()` method?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `class Nested` is an [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) and therefore has an implicit reference to the instance of `TopLevel` that encloses it.

You need an *instance* of the `Nested` class to access `someMethod`

```
private void someMethod() {
    new Nested().someMethod();
}
```

Because your `Nested` class is not `static` it is tied to an instance of `TopLevel` - you can access this instance using `TopLevel.this`.

This same does not apply the other way around, there is no implicit instance of `Nested` tied to `TopLevel`. You need to explicitly create an instance of `Nested` in order to access its non-`static` members.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of `Nested` such that the instance method `someMethod` can be invoked

```
new Nested().someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
new Nested().someMethod();
```

As it is non static inner class , you need to create an instance to access it's methods

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it staticly, make nested a static class and the method static